# Is there a way to have Docker on Mac fallback to linux/amd64 when a linux/arm64 image is not available?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using a Mac with an M1 chip for development work. When using Docker to run various containers (via docker-compose), I often have to modify the docker-compose.yml file to specify `platform: linux/amd64` (and make sure the docker-compose.yml's `version` is at least `2.4`).

Here is an example of the type of error message I frequently see:

```
Error response from daemon: image with reference phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5 was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64, actual: linux/amd64
```

Is there a way to have Docker / Docker Compose (on a Mac) try to use the linux/arm64 version, but if it's not available, automatically fall back to the linux/amd64 image?

Answer (score 2):

You can `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` but that won't be a fallback and will prevent you from using native images whenever available.

EDIT: upstream feature request:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10579

Comment: Thank you for submitting the feature request(s) 